# OLE DB Origin connection dynamically changes and retrieves settings from a table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I have the scenario below:

97 SQLEXPRESS instances from 97 different servers. Each instance has a database with the same name and schema. I need to retrieve one table from all 97 servers and export it to a separate SQL Server 2019 server to control and generate reports.

Edited: The need for SQL EXPRESS on 97 servers is because those servers are installed on 97 OIL platforms in the middle of the sea. To avoid connectivity issues, each platform has its own environment.

I've created an SSIS project in Visual Studio 2022 to handle this data export, which I can deploy on an SSIS server to run daily. My package includes a foreach loop with an expression variable for the origin connection to dynamically change servers.

[image: Control Flow]

In the Control Flow, I've set up an Execute SQL Task to retrieve my server table from the SQL Server using this query:

SELECT table, instance, base, codserver
FROM dbo.Server
WHERE active = 1

Then, I load the results into the User::Tablelist variable of type Object.

In my Foreach loop, I use an "Enumerator ADO foreach" with the User::TableList as the "ADO source Variable". Then, in the "Variable Mapping" section, I map User::table, User::instance, User::base, and User::codserver.

[image: Data Flow]

In the Data Flow, I create an OLE DB Origin and use an expression to dynamically set the Initial Catalog and ServerName from my variables.

I add a new column to include the codserver column, which indicates the server from which the information is being retrieved. This column will be used for filtering after the export.

Then i add the Ole DB Destination.

---

Edited: My destination server is a licensed SQL Server 2019 Standard with licensed SSIS and Report Server as well.

This setup works in development. However, I encounter issues when deploying it to my SSIS server because I can't export the variables I created in the Visual Studio project.

I attempted to use package parameters, but I encountered difficulties accessing the column from the server table and incorporating it into my parameters to configure my connections.

I'm exploring alternative solutions using XML, JSON, or any other method. If I can't find a better alternative, I may resort to creating a package to generate a separate connection for each of the 97 servers, although this seems inefficient.

Can someone assist me in finding a more efficient way to accomplish this?

My primary concern is finding a solution that can be deployed once for a daily SSIS job for all 97 servers.

Comment: I am honestly questioning why you have ***ninety seven*** separate Express instances...

Comment: `any of 97 servers` why ??? That's horribly wasteful. If you want to create a multitenant database server, you can create 97 databases, not servers. A single Standard server will be faster and cheaper than provisioning 97 Express with their limitations

Comment: I think I understand the pattern of what you're want to accomplish. Your network has SQL Express installed on many machines, like you're a retail store or bodegas or you have sensors installed collecting data. Those instances are all the same and you need to get the data at close of business - something like that. Where I'm fuzzy is the problem statement about deploying SSIS packages and an exporting variables. Can you click Edit and try to explain better what the problem is? Also, when you are deploying your package, what Edition of SQL Server are you targeting: Express, Standard, Enterprise?

Comment: In any case, you can load *settings* [from configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-5-2-enabling-and-configuring-package-configurations?view=sql-server-ver16), not variables. Variables store runtime data, just like variables in any programming language. You can store settings to variables. You can store query results to variables, thus allowing you to create connection strings from a list of tenants. You can also create a loop over query results, using a loop variable as the current item value

Comment: Well that can't deploy to Express, @billinkc , SSIS requires Standard as a minimum. Running SSIS in any way without such a purchase is a breach of the licence agreement.

Comment: @billinkc if that's the case, replication is probably a better option, as long as the central server is Standard at least.

Comment: Correct, the only way SSIS works with Express is through the Import/Export wizard, which _we_ know but I wanted to understand what they think they're doing. Seems English is not their first language and I thought explaining their deployment strategy might help me better understand their core problem.

Comment: The SQL EXPRESS is required on 97 servers because those servers are installed on 97 OIL platforms in the middle of the sea. Each platform has its own environment to avoid connectivity issues. My destination is a licensed SQL Server 2019 Standard with SSIS and Report Server for use.